# How to find other friends of friendslist on facebook using Java API

Tags: java, facebook

Am working on Facebook Application in java. Now in my application i can able to connect to facebook and retrieve my friends list. but i want to know how will i get my friends friends list. for eg "A" user has looged in and A has got b,c,d,e as his friendslist. i want to know the b's friendlist of A.

Any help is appreciable

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get the friend's list of your friend b, until you login with that b's credentials. Else you'll get OAuthException, which means you are not authorised or need a accesstoken / session of that particular user. Let me know why you need this maybe I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Via the graph API this would be:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/<user_id_for_b>/friends
```